# How do I run development and deployment at the same time?

Tags: reactjs, git, web, next.js, deployment

I am working on a website for a company for Internal purposes and I am hosting the NextJS project on a server provided by the company. I want to deploy and make this website available at the current state to the users but also want to continue development of the project perhaps in a different folder(I can only work on this project directly on the server using remote connection) and then once I am ready to deploy the developed version, perhaps use git to merge the changes. But I am unable to setup a local repository to push and pull from properly. How could I achieve this using git or do suggest if you have any other better means.

Thank you.

I have tried setting up git but when I initialise git as "bare" I am unable to push and when I dont do as "bare", I am unable to remote add the folder.

Comment: It's not really clear to me what kind of setup you're trying to describe (though statements like *"I can only work on this project directly on the server"* are... troubling).  How do you currently deploy the built code to the server?  Why can't you perform that process whenever you have a new version to release?

Comment: There is a windows server I can access via "remote Desktop Connection" where I can work on the project. I directly work on this remote PC/server and can deploy on a particular port on this. I want to have a way where there are two folders in this remote server, one for deployment and one for development and to be able to push changes to deployment folder once I am ready to deploy the next version instead of copy pasting the files between folders manually.

Comment: Aside from the fact that you *really* should get development moved to a non-production workstation... What is the "deployment" process for the application in general?  For React apps, isn't there an `npm build` or something similar which produces the final compiled output into a folder?  If that's the case, isn't that exactly the process you just described?  That is... Working in the source code (which itself is tracked with Git) and then running a build/deploy which produces the output?  At worst you could add an `npm` command which builds and outputs to another folder, no?

Comment: About moving to a non production workstation, it is completely out of my hand. Yes, I use the 'npm run build' to build the project and use 'npm start' to start it on a port but to my knowledge, it does not create a different folder for it and when I do changes for my development, I get an 'Internal Server Error' on the website and the build does not run. Thank you for your input until now.